# jsf primefaces selectOne menu default value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{lead.status}" >

                    <f:selectItem itemValue="v0" itemLabel="l3" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="v1" itemLabel="l1"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="v2" itemLabel="l2"/>

                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

My goal is to make selectOne menu which will by default select one of this options.(I don't know which one it is different all the time.
Not the first one.How to do this?

LEt's say I have in my backbean

```
String optionToSelectBydefault = "v1"
```

So how to make my selectOneMenu select v1 By default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this:

The default value will be the one which is equal to

> value="#{lead.status}" >

So thanks=)